# Which type of electric motor I need?

Tags: electrical-engineering, motors

For an experiment I need to use an electric motor, unfortunately I'm not an expert of electric machines. The electric motor I need has to comply with some requests:

1. It must be brushless.
2. It has always to turn at low speed, from 0 to max 6 rad/s.
3. Its width can't exceed 2cm and its diameter can't exceed 11cm.
4. It is energized by a battery.
5. It has to develop a quite intense torque.

So I'd like to know which type of electric motor meets these requests (if any).

Comment: Gear it down. That will solve both 2 and 5.

Comment: @ratchetfreak I can't do it due to the position in which the motor has to stay

Comment: 11x11x2 cm is quite a lot of space to gear down a small motor

Comment: Might be good tell us about the type of brushless motor you are currently considering. Also it would be if you can define intense Torque. What desired battery specification. Currently the question is too broad, and might not be able to be answered in this forum.

Comment: @Mahendra How I' ve said I'm not an expert, I'm a physicist not an engineer, so I don't know about the classification of brushless motor, I just know that a brushed motor isn't appropriate for my experiment. The torque must be about 50 nm. The battery hasn't 
requirements to satisfy (each type can be used).

Comment: How about a stepper motor? Do you have any sketches to share?

Comment: @Mahendra I read that stepper motor are good to turn at slow speed so it can be a good idea, but I read here (http://www.berryjam.eu/2015/04/driving-bldc-gimbals-at-super-slow-speeds-with-arduino/) that also a BLDC motor can work at slow speed. Which is the best choice in your opinion?

Comment: 11 cm diameter by 2 cm width?  By that do you mean the axial length of the motor can only be 2 cm long?  Essentially you have a cylinder that is 11 cm in diameter and 2 cm long that the motor has to fit in?  If so, you aren't going to find a motor that meets your criteria.

Comment: @Eric yes right a cylinder 11x2. No motors with these dimensions, are you sure?

Comment: You can get brushless motors that are sometimes called "pancake" motors that look like, well, pancakes.  Very short compared to the outer diameter.  My comment had more to do with the amount of torque you are trying to get from that volume. Is 50 Nm your continuous torque or your maximum torque?

Comment: 50 nm is an enormous torque, especially that you need a motor with such a small dimensions. Are you sure about this requirement?

Comment: Ok, let's say that between all the motors that satisfy the other 4 points I want the one that is able to develop the most intese torque. 50 Nm would be beautifull but also inferior values can be accepted. @Eric

Comment: @JohnDoe the comment above is my answer. (I can use the @ for only one user for each comment)

Comment: @Landau I believe the type of motor you're looking for is stepper motor. It's brushless, it can rotate at low speed, it can be powered by a battery, and it has one with 11 cm diameter, it's called NEMA 42 size. However, 2 cm length is not common, I'm not really sure you can find such a thin motor if you're not asking for it to be custom made.. And the torque, it will be far lower than your expectation. The largest NEMA 42 stepper motor that I know has about 40 nm torque, it's length is 23 cm.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more impossible it seems. I was thinking that maybe an e-bike "hubmotor" would work. They are meant to fit inside a bike wheel. But those would be well over 2 cm wide and over 11 cm diameter and still would probably not produce the torque you need.  Torque is proportional to diameter squared and length of the motor.

Comment: Speed can be controlled by your drive circuit and controller. I have found stepper motors used in application that need some type of feedback such as robots, camera zoom etc. I have found brushless motor in applications such as fans. Brushless motor tend to be cheaper than stepper motors. Also you can measure speed  if a magnet and hall effect sensor is use in with a brushless motor. There are various ways to solve problems. Looks like @JohnDoe and @ Eric has some good suggestions. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Here are some source for you investing with regard to Brushless motors. Take look at the Hobby Robotic Motor Vendor. For the most part they a good source to visualize possible solution. Also it might be best to narrow down a target supply voltage and possible battery options.

**High Volume Vendors**

- [Brushless DC Motor Speed Control Systems](http://orientalmotor.com/brushless-dc-motors/index.html)
- [Brushless DC Motors](https://www.moonsindustries.com/Moons-Category/Brushless-DC-Motors/c/A05)
- [MinebeaMitsumi Group BRUSHLESS DC MOTORS](http://www.nmbtc.com/brushless-dc-motors/)
- [Delta Group Brushless DC Motors (H/A Motors)](http://www.deltaww.com/Products/CategoryListT1.aspx?CID=030501&PID=ALL&hl=en-US)
- [Hansen Precision Electric Motors](http://www.hansen-motor.com/)
- [Leili Micro-motor](http://www.czleili.com/english/products_class_87.html)
- [ZHAOWEI - zwgearbox - Standard Planetary Gearbox](http://www.zwgearbox.com/StandardPlanetaryGea.shtml)
- [JVL INTEGRATED SERVO MOTORS AND STEPPER MOTORS](http://jvlusa.com/)

**Hobby Robotic Motor Vendors**

- [ROBOTICS & CNC / MOTORS](https://www.adafruit.com/category/229)
- [Pololu Mechanical Components Motors and Gearboxes](https://www.pololu.com/category/22/motors-and-gearboxes)
- [Sparkfun Motors and Drivers](https://www.sparkfun.com/categories/178?page=all)

Hope these resource will help you get started.